# WooCommerce products API responds with empty array

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have been stuck for the past week on an issue I don't understand and didn't find anywhere somebody having the same issue.

I have installed the latest version of the WooCommerce plugin for Wordpress and I am trying to use the API to get products for an angular Wordpress theme.

I set up my development machine to use SSL (https) cause it seems to be a mess to do without and I created a pair of key/secret for testing purpose.

I added products into the admin part for WooCommerce products (~10) but when I go on the url of the api (`<base_url>/wc-api/v3/products?consumer_key=...&consumer_secret=...`) I have in response NOT AN ERROR, but just an empty array.

```
{
   products: [ ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? :'(

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of client libraries that make things a lot easier. I suggest you try these to see if you get the same result.

https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#official-libraries

And just to be sure: are your products set as being "published" and "public"? Otherwise the API will not include them.

Comment: Public and published, yes. The thing is, I wanted to read that thanks to my browser, to eventually fetch it with an angular app.